# Adding WMTS to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tiles, wmts

I cannot add the below map server (Middle_East_Oil_and_Gas_Field_Map_by_CIA (WMTS) to qgis through add WMS/WMTS layer.

A connection will not be made to the following URL.

URL: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ULBqC49IEeIR01GF/arcgis/rest/services/Middle_East_Oil_and_Gas_Field_Map_by_CIA/MapServer?view=wmtsview&cacheKey=aec62228d3e2389d

What am I doing wrong?

QGIS version 2.18.26

Comment: This is no WMS-server, it's an online-map.

Comment: @Erik It is a WMTS and works in ArcGIS online.

Comment: Not with that url it isn't

Comment: I thought I found my answer here but I am having a problem with a similar tiles.arcgis.com location. I apologize if I am not following format but I offer another solution at the end and would appreciate any help with the following MapServer as none of the above solutions worked. The the following URL is what I am having trouble loading in QGIS 3.4. https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/pDAi2YK0L0QxVJHj/arcgis/rest/services/2018_Douglas_Imagery/MapServer/ If I add the previous link to QGIS 3.4 as a ArcGISMapServer Connection the image comes in but is all blurry, pixelated, stretched, and only seen thi

Answer (score 3):

You can use this url as WMTS service in QGIS:

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ULBqC49IEeIR01GF/arcgis/rest/services/Middle_East_Oil_and_Gas_Field_Map_by_CIA/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=aec62228d3e2389d
```

Comment: That is some black magic. How did you do that? Can you please refer me to any kind of reference where I can get more about rewriting the URL in such smart way?

Comment: If you shorten the original url to https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ULBqC49IEeIR01GF/arcgis/rest/services/ in a browser, you will find the ArcGIS Services Directory. There you can navigate to the correct layer and find a link to the WMTS service.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the map as "XYZ Tiles" layer using the following URL:

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ULBqC49IEeIR01GF/arcgis/rest/services/Middle_East_Oil_and_Gas_Field_Map_by_CIA/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Middle_East_Oil_and_Gas_Field_Map_by_CIA/default/default028mm/{z}/{y}/{x}.png
```

Notice the variables `{z}`, `{y}`, `{x}` at the end.

I checked it using QGIS 3.4, but should also work with 2.18. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_RAXylFLfk).